# 7zip Script to Exclude Files and Folders not working

Tags: backup, 7zip

I have created a 7zip script that backs up folders listed in the file `c:\Backup\include.txt`, however I am also trying to exclude certain files and folders which I have listed in the the file `C:\Backup\exclude.txt`, whilst it backs up all of the folders listed in `include.txt`, it does not exclude any files or folders listed in `exclude.txt`

I am using 7za v18.1

```
C:\Backup\7za.exe a -t7z -mx9 -v4g -x@C:\Backup\exclude.txt "F:\BackupFiles\7zipBackup.7z" @C:\Backup\include.txt
```

`include.txt`

> C:\Users\Chris\Dropbox\

`exclude.txt`

> C:\Users\Chris\Dropbox\Apps
>
> *.tmp
>
> ~$*.*
>
> desktop.ini
>
> ~*.*
>
> *~.*
>
> *.~*
>
> *.*~
>
> *.lock

Can anyone help?

Comment: does this solve your problem?

Comment: You should include which language you are using.